# How to prove that the exterior angle sum of an n-sided polygon is 360 degrees?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-writing

Just wondering about the smartest and best way to prove such a question. I know of many ways, and also I don't want to use anything related to $180(n - 2)$.

Comment: By dividing the n-gon into n-2 triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what are you looking for, but perhaps try this:

You can divide the n-sided polygon into n triangles. Every triangle has the angle sum of 180°. We are not interested in the 360° from the circle around the middle point, so we have:
$n \cdot 180°-360°$

Comment: you should read my title - How to prove that the exterior angle sum of an n-sided polygon is 360 degrees?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively it isn't too hard to see since as you trace round the shape you make one complete full turn so must go through a total of 360 degrees.

See this picture, [link](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?q=exterior%20angle%20sum&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1027&bih=673&tbm=isch&tbnid=LXCP6ahr5ZfuZM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/ks3bitesize/maths/shape_space/polygons/revise3.shtml&imgurl=http://www.bbc.co.uk/ks3bitesize/maths/images/exterior_angles.gif&w=516&h=304&ei=AWxEUMaTI-jU0QXLuYDICg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=122&vpy=166&dur=2241&hovh=172&hovw=293&tx=146&ty=99&sig=103024795917893489109&page=1&tbnh=149&tbnw=261&start=0&ndsp=13&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:73). Imagine moving the angles to a point along the lines, they make a full turn.

For a formal proof the only way I can think of at the moment is to use the fact that the interior angle sum is $180(n-2)$. Given the exterior angles $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$, the interior angles are $180-\alpha_1, 180-\alpha_2, ..., 180-\alpha_n$.

Summing these gives the interior angle sum to be $180n - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_n$. But this has to equal $180(n-2)$. Rearranging gives $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 360$.

Answer (score 0):

This may be completely wrong, it seems far too easy. But I can't see any error, so here goes. This proof tries to bring the theorem closer to the "walking around the polygon" intuition.

Let $(u_1...u_n)$ be an n-tuple of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $u_1 = u_n$. The angle between two successive vectors in this sequence is $\angle u_{i+1} - \angle u_i$, where $\angle v$ is the angle that $v$ makes with the positive x-axis. The sum of these angles is:

$$\sum_{1}^{n-1}{(\angle u_{i+1} - \angle u_i)}$$
$$=\sum_{1}^{n-1}{\angle u_{i+1} - \sum_{1}^{n-1}\angle u_i}$$
$$=\sum_{2}^{n}{\angle u_{i} - \sum_{1}^{n-1}\angle u_i}$$
$$=\sum_{2}^{n-1}{\angle u_{i} + \angle u_n - \sum_{2}^{n-1}\angle u_i} - \angle u_1$$
$$=0$$

The sides of a polygon and the exterior angles between them are simply a special case of this proposition.